# How do I retrieve a token from a post to PHP?

Tags: php, post

I want to retrieve the token as seen in the developer console image below. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Image not showing

Answer (score -1):

PHP gets the raw request, and if you send JSON content it can get the raw data with the below method:

```
$postRaw = file_get_contents("php://input");

print_r($postRaw);
```

Sometimes `$_POST` return empty  but if `$_POST` return data , you can basically use `$_POST['postname']`:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Mean s $_POST return empty